# How to scheduling the processes

Tags: c, operating-system, scheduled-tasks

I have problem with scheduling the processes homework and i need help.

Process         P1    P2    P3     P4   P5
Service time    120   60    180    50   300

```
Draw a Gantt chart that shows the completion times for each process using
```

the following CPU scheduling:

1. first-come, first served CPU
2. shortest-job-first
3. round-robin with a time slice of 60.

   Priority    Arrival Time        Service Time
   P0  1               3                  5
   P1  2               2                  6
   P2  1               4                  7
   P3  2               1                  3
4. Draw a Gantt chart that shows the completion times for each process using each of the following CPU Scheduling Techniques (non-preemptive). Then Calculate the Average Waiting Time and the Average Turn Around Time for each Case.
   a)  first-come, first served 
   b)  Shortest-Job-First
   c)  Priority Scheduling
   d)  Round Robin Scheduling ( q = 5)

Comment: Any I/O, any calls to 'sleep()`, etc etc etc will modify the order of the output,

Comment: exactly what you mean by all those numbers is not quite clear.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free coding service, not a free software design service.  Show us what you have tried and explain how its' output differs from what you expected  I.E. post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there's time. At "time=0" you can figure out (for each scheduler, except round robin maybe) which process will be given CPU time first, then determine how much time it will run for (for each scheduler, including round robin), then draw a line on your Gantt chart showing how long the process used the CPU for. Then you'll have a new value for "time" (from when the first process stopped using CPU time, at the end of the line you just drew), so you'd repeat the same steps to figure out which process gets CPU time next and draw another line; and you'd keep doing this (for each scheduler) until all the processes have finished.

You can/should try this on a piece of paper - like a rough draft. If you understand how each of the scheduling algorithms work it's not hard (and if you don't know how some of the scheduling algorithms work it's easy to find out - e.g. find a search engine and ...).

The only problem that I can see is that the order that processes are given CPU time isn't specified for round robin. You could say that (for round robin) P1 gets CPU time first,  or P2 gets CPU time first, or ... I'd be tempted to assume they're given CPU time in numerical order (P1 gets CPU time first, then P2, then P3, ..); but I'd also state whatever assumption I made.